Reuse Django's admin form template for my own forms
When the Django admin renders one of its forms, the fields are rendered with HTML like so:
<div class="form-row field-comment">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <label for="id_comment">Comment:</label>
      <input type="text" name="comment" class="vTextField" maxlength="200" id="id_comment">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

When I add my own page to the admin interface and I render a form using {{ form }}, the layout is completely different, and the same field would be rendered like this:
<div>
  <label for="id_comment">Comment:</label>
  <input type="text" name="comment" id="id_comment">
</div>

How can I reuse Django’s form template for my own forms?
This is my full HTML template:
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>
&rsaquo; {{ title }}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Generate codes">
</form>
{% endblock %}

I include this extra page in the admin by setting up get_urls in the ModelAdmin class, and returning a TemplateResponse with the form instance.
I've tried adding field_template_name = "admin/includes/fieldset.html" to my form class, but that doesn't make any difference.
